# Calculate user reputation on creation of vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question and answer app that is similar in the way stackoverflow works. The vote model is polymorphic and belongs to 3 other models. A vote is created via a member POST route on each model using a vote method in each controller.

The following `user_reputation` method which works and sets the user reputation by adding the "second" value of the vote (+5 for up, -3 for down) to the existing user reputation upon creation of a vote, however it feels like bad practice to set the values of the vote like this.

Is there a cleaner/ best practice way to achieve this?

vote.rb

```
attr_accessible :value, :votable_id, :votable_type
belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user

validates_inclusion_of :value, in: [1, -1]
validates_presence_of :user_id, :value, :votable_id, :votable_type
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :votable_id
validates_uniqueness_of :value, scope: :votable_id

after_create :sum_votes

after_create :user_reputation

def user_reputation
    votable = self.votable_type.downcase
    user_rep = self.votable.user
    if self.value == 1
      user_rep.update_attributes(reputation: (user_rep.reputation + 5))
    elsif self.value == -1
      user_rep.update_attributes(reputation: (user_rep.reputation - 3))
    end
  end
```

vote _form.html.erb

```
<div class="vote">
    <div id='<%= "#{votes_count}_#{id}" %>' class="vote-box">
        <div class='<%= object.votes_count < 0 ? 'orange-arrows' : 'default-arrows' %>'>
            <h1><%= object.votes_count %></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="arrows">
    <%= link_to raw("&#9650;"), vote_path.call(object, value: 1),id: "upvote", remote: true,  method: "post" %><br>
    <%= link_to raw(" &#9660;") , vote_path.call(object, value: -1), id: "downvote", remote: true, method: "post" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :answers do 
    member { post :vote }
  end

  resources :questions do 
    member { post :vote }
  end 

  resources :comments do 
    member { post :vote }
  end
```

controller method

```
def vote 
    @vote = current_user.votes.build(value: params[:value], votable_id: params[:id], votable_type: "Answer")
    respond_to do |format|
    if @vote.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "Vote submitted" }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: "You can't vote on your own content" }
      format.js
    end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Active Record Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html). It actually the same as what you are doing, but it lets you separate these logic from your model.

And i don't think you need the first line in the user_reputation method.

- Removed from core in Rails 4.0 -> https://github.com/rails/rails-observers

Comment: this was cool, has moved off a lot of logic into another class and gave me a chance to refactor nicely as well.